# How to animate the background color of a QPushButton in qt?

Tags: python, c++, qt, animation, pyqt4

I did everything [till what i know] to animate the background color of a button but i can't do it. Here are one of my tries:

```
    # I set the style of the button by setstylesheet()
    animation = QPropertyAnimation(btn, "style",btn)
    animation.setDuration(1000)
    animation.setStartValue(QStyle("background-color:blue"))
    animation.setEndValue(QStyle("background-color:red"))
    animation.start()
```

But the following code shows the following error:

**animation.setStartValue(QStyle("background-color:blue"))
TypeError: PyQt4.QtGui.QStyle represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated**

I also tried to set a palette:

```
    color = install_btn.palette()
    color.setColor(QPalette.Base,QColor(72, 152, 219))
    install_btn.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    install_btn.setPalette(color)
```

and then instead of `QStyle` in above animation value i wrote `QColor(r,g,b)` but that too didn't worked, it said:

**QPropertyAnimation: you're trying to animate a non-existing property style of your QObject**

Please help me in any language you know (C++ or Python). But i use Python.

Thanks is special

Comment: `QStyle` is an abstract base class and cannot be instantiated. You're also using the wrong background color for your palette. You should use `QPalette.Button` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++, Qt5, but may work in Qt4

```
QGraphicsColorizeEffect *eEffect= new QGraphicsColorizeEffect(btn);
btn->setGraphicsEffect(eEffect);
QPropertyAnimation *paAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(eEffect,"color");
paAnimation->setStartValue(QColor(Qt::blue));
paAnimation->setEndValue(QColor(Qt::red));
paAnimation->setDuration(1000);
paAnimation->start();
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't worked :( even there was no error. Color was changed but there was no animation in it. Is something missing from your code?

Comment: @AhmadTaha I think you made an error when translating code to python.

Comment: no, i did not, there was no error + i know little c++

Comment: i just change the QColor in rgb instead

Comment: @AhmadTaha try the example without changing color